# Find the orthogonal projection of v onto the subspace W spanned by the vectors ui

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm going this homework problem and I'm stuck and was hoping someone would be able the clarify something for me.

v = [1,2,3] and u1 = [1,1,1,] and u2 = [1,-1,0]

u1.v = 6
u1.u1 = 3
u2.v = -1
u2.u2 = 0

projw(V) = (u1.v/u1.u1)u1 + (u2.v/u2.u2)u2

projw(V) = (6/3)[1,1,1] + (-1/0)[1,-1,0]

This is where I'm stuck. As you can see I have -1/0 which is infinity or undefined. So, is my whole solution now infinity or undefined?? I've double checked my work so I believe that I've done all the math correctly.

Comment: $u_2 \cdot u_2 = 2$, not $0$. No nonzero vector can ever be orthogonal to itself.

Comment: Oh lord, im so stupid! I see it now. Thank you

Comment: Oh, and it is 2 because u2.u2 = 1+1+0 = 2

Comment: You are welcome.